# Adding users via flyway DB migration

Tags: database-migration, flyway

I've read in some articles that it's best practice NOT to add DB users via flyway db migration. It's not very clear to me as to why it's not a good practice. One thing we thought about is that it might be good to have the user configuration automatically documented in the code.

One article mentioned that you might want different user configuration for different environments. But you could also control that in flyway.

When/why would you not want to add DB users using flyway DB migration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm deploying a new user for the database that will be common across all environments, I would absolutely make the creation of that user a part of the Flyway deployment scripts. It fundamentally makes sense. "Version 43.43 is where we added the login snarglegrass to the app."

On the other hand, if you are working on setting up different environments with varying permissions, I probably will make that part of the flow control commands in pre/post deployment scripts instead of using Flyway. The reason for this is because it can be challenging to write the scripts in such a way as they're repeatable and safe. You could still do it that way though.